# Как загрузить фотки с фронтенда?

Tags: php, laravel, octobercms

Имеются плагины https://octobercms.com/plugin/fireunion-blogfront и https://octobercms.com/plugin/responsiv-uploader 
Нужно загружать картинки к посту

вот код страницы:

```
title = "testupload"
url = "/testupload"
is_hidden = 0
child_of = "mey_no_parent"
hide_crumb = 0
remove_crumb_trail = 0
crumb_disabled = 0

[Ajax]
use_authors = 1
restrict_owner = 1
backUser = 1
allowpublish = 1
postPage = "blog/post"

[Responsiv\Uploader\Components\ImageUploader imageUploader]
placeholderText = "Click or drag images to upload"
maxSize = 5
fileTypes = ".gif,.jpg,.jpeg,.png"
imageWidth = 100
imageHeight = 100
imageMode = "crop"
==
<?php


function onInit()
{
    $this->fileUploader->bindModel('photos', ????????? );
}
?>
==
{% component 'Ajax' %}
{% component 'imageUploader' %}
```

Я никак не могу разобраться, что должно быть вместо вопросов? Есть ли примеры?

Comment: https://octobercms.com/plugin/responsiv-uploader   Вот тут в разделе "документация" есть пример использования, в котором вместо ????  указан id модели

Comment: Спасибо. Модель и метод методом тыка нашёл